# The second moment of a exponential plus constant

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I have a distribution with Y=1/4+X where X is a exponential distibution with mean 1/4. Now what I need to to get the second moment: $E[Y^2]= E[(1/4+X)^2]$, the awnser states that this is 5/16 but i cannot figure out why.

Comment: That can't be right, it is at least 3/4. Perhaps 5/16 is the variance?

Comment: It does day that the second moment is 5/16, so I don't know either.